# Javascript Reference Error in html form

Tags: javascript, html, reference

this code returns "ReferenceError: work is not defined" when clicking the submit button and I haven't found why. (I'm also using CakePHP)
My idea is to create a validator object, create functions in it, and then instantiate and use it.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('validate'); ?>
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
        <form name="form" action="mailtest.php" method="post">
            name <input type="text" name="name">
            mail <input type="text" name="mail">
            comment <input type="text" name="comment">
            <input type="button" name="button" value="click" 
            onClick="work(this.form)">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var validator = function() {

    var name;
    name = form.name.value;
    var mail;
    mail = form.mail.value;
    var comment;
    comment = form.comment.value;

    validate: function()
    {

        form.name.value = "NO!";
    }

}

function work(form)
{
    v = new validator();
    v.validate();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in this case (weird) Cakephp didn't recognize the file by calling it with echo $this->HTML->script(validate); so I had to use validate.js .....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check your syntax  it is not valid. You cannot set properties to function like you do with `validate: function() {...}`. 
Secondly, you don't path `this.work` to validator so it won't be defined inside it.
Thirdly, I am not sure this is a good idea to make new instance ob object every time you click the button. Why don't just use simple function call here?

```
<head>
    <script>
        function validate(form) {

            var name = form.name.value,
                mail = form.mail.value,
                comment = form.comment.value;

            form.name.value = "NO!";


        };

        function work(form) {
            validate(form);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form name="form" action="mailtest.php" method="post">name
        <input type="text" name="name">mail
        <input type="text" name="mail">comment
        <input type="text" name="comment">
        <input type="button" name="button" value="click" onClick="work(this.form)">
    </form>
</body>
```

Also, if want want to understand objects in JS (it can be tricky) and you them, I would recommend you read this two blog posts: [JavaScript Objects in Detail](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/) and [OOP In JavaScript: What You NEED to Know](http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/).

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand what you mean by " you don't path this.work to validator so it won't be defined inside it. "

Comment: I meant you dont't PASS the argument to 'validate()' function (or costructor),  or in other words there should be argument 'form' in your `validate()` function to make code correct.
however, I was not 100% correct in your situtation. You code will work, because when you gave name "form" to your form, property `form` was added to `window` object, so form is actually defined in your function as part of global scope. However, if you change your form's name to, for example, "form1" and then call `validate()` without arguments, you will get error that form is not defined.

Comment: on onclick I do: validate(this.form)
and JavaScript code is now:
`code`
var name, mail, comment;

function validate(form)
{
 name = form.name.value;
 mail = form.mail.value;
 comment = form.comment.value;
 form.name.value = "NO!";
}
`code`

still not working... (same error but applied to validate)

Comment: I was talking about the initial code (check your question again :)), where you actually call work(this.form) on click and in work() function both instantiated validator and called validate() function without any arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you change your validator function to the following the error disappears

```
var validator = function() {

var name;
name = form.name.value;
var mail;
mail = form.mail.value;
var comment;
comment = form.comment.value;

this.validate = function()
{

    form.name.value = "NO!";
}
```

}